Why is Xubuntu giving me these errors and crashes
I upgraded Xubuntu 22.04 to the latest 24.04, but as soon as I boot up or reboot the system I get 2 crash errors one for xfce4-panel and xfce4/panel/wrapper-2.0 and SIGABRT. Even when I do a fresh install and don't touch anything these errors keep poping up as soon as you boot up the system. Does anyone have similar problem with latest LTS Xubuntu how do you fix this. The error will also happen as soon as you change font's on the default panel, add-move plugins or change dpkgs-locales. Is the latest Xubuntu panel broken why do these errors happen on a fresh install as well?



















Is there a way to pass this to the developers somehow as well it ruins the user experince before you even get started or touch anything.

the packaged libs are wrong
Gaël Bonithon from Xfce, the maintainer of xfce4-panel, says that

you updated glib to 2.80 on Ubuntu 24.04, but left xfce4-panel at 4.18.4. However, a patch released in xfce4-panel 4.18.6 is required when using glib 2.80

I have the same problem, but still don't have the time (and skills) to build my own .deb package and host my own repo to update xfce4-panel within apt (and get automatic updates in the apt framework, instead of maintaining a loose software installation). This would be my suggestion to fix this.
I'm waiting for the maintainers to update the xfce4-panel.
Edit to add: according to this mint thread there is a .deb available in the debian repo here: debian repo
